# How to put chrome in Device Mode (to enable Touch events) using Javascript (or Electron)

Tags: google-chrome, webkit, electron

Hello is there a way to put Chrome in Device mode using Javascript (or Electron configuration) for desktop browser?

We have an app that we need touch events on a Electron desktop app which have a touchscreen connected, however the OS does not treat the device as a touch panel but rather just a mouse with pointer. So we want to force our Web App (through Javascript or Electron configuration)

Here is my electron code:

```
mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({width: 1024, height: 768,
    webPreferences: {
      blinkFeatures : 'Touch'
    },
    icon: __dirname + '/assets/img/logo.png'});
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think that you need the device to specifically support touch events for the application to behave correctly.

However you could try setting the [touch-events](http://chrome://flags/#touch-events) flag manually and see if that helps.

In your main process, before you create your `BrowserWindow` set the following flag:

```
app.commandLine.appendSwitch('--enable-touch-events')
```

Comment: I added that line and still the view is geared towards mouse pointer and not touch event which can hit areas

Comment: I'm pretty sure the device itself will need to send touch events in that case. Some of those old school "touch" devices aren't true touch devices in the modern sense.

Comment: According to this https://electronjs.org/docs/api/chrome-command-line-switches
That options is not available

Comment: It used to be, let us know if you find the new way and I'll update.